Multiple recurring 'Get Azure SQL Database(s) List' operations in 1 Azure Runbook
I have 1 runbook automatically scaling my Azure SQL Database. I noticed the operation is taking longer and longer taking over 45 minutes, while scaling manually takes only a few minutes.
Upon inspecting the Database activity log, I notice that that are multiple 'Get Azure SQL Database(s) List'  operations going on, up to 50 times, around 3 times each minute, all started by the Automation account.
Get Azure SQL Database(s) List operations
The runbook has only 3 steps:

Connect AZ Account,
Get connection information,
Set-AZSQLDatabase (to scale from S0 to S6)

The runbook:
Runbook screenshot
I fear this is causing too much traffic to scale efficiently, taking over 50 minutes for a single scaling action
I expect the set-azsqldatabase cmdlet to perform 1 get-azsqldatabase cmdlet. Inspecting the runbook does not give any indication there is a recurring action. Yet each upscaling action results in multiple 'Get Azure SQL Database(s) List' operations.

add if you are facing any error

If you run a SQL command from PowerShell instead, the database scale up/down process will be much faster and reliable.
$sqlCommand.CommandText= "ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] MODIFY (EDITION = 'Premium', MAXSIZE = 1024 GB, SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P2');"

$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

